# Minimized query fetch time

Tags: sql, informix

Following is my query which takes 10 minutes for fetching 9 mn records from an Informix database

```
select x.no ,x.code ,x.type ,sum(x.val) as val from 
(SELECT a.d_no as no,a.s_code as code, b.type as type, sum(a.value) as val                  
FROM TABLE1 a, TABLE2 b,TABLE3 c
WHERE c.segment_id=b.cat AND c.b_id=b.sub_cat
AND a.terminated_date is null AND a.d_no=c.d_no AND a.s_code=c.s_code
GROUP BY b.type ,b.cat,b.sub_cat, no, code 
union all
SELECT a.d_no as no,a.s_code as code,     
b.type as type,sum(a.value) as val                  
FROM TABLE4 a, TABLE2 b, TABLE3 c
WHERE c.segment_id=b.cat AND c.b_id=b.sub_cat
AND a.terminated_date is null AND a.d_no=c.d_no AND a.s_code=c.s_code
GROUP BY b.type ,b.cat,b.sub_cat, no, code) x
group by x.code ,x.no ,x.type
```

Comment: have you try create index? since query itself isn't that complicated therefor isn't really improvable.

Comment: Can you provide the execution plan for your query please. Also, just as an FYI, you really should be writing your SQL using ANSI SQL joins (INNER, LEFT OUTER, etc) - the join format you're using hasn't been considered to be good practice for years

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  It doesn't affect performance but it does make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: How big are the tables?  How many rows? How many columns? What is the size of each row in bytes.  What indexes exist on each table on the columns referenced in the query?  This is crucial information for evaluating performance concerns.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try rewriting your query so there is no confusion/ambiguity for the "Informix optimizer":

> ```
> SELECT x.no, x.code, x.type,
> SUM(x.val) val 
> FROM (
>    SELECT a.d_no no, a.s_code code, b.type type, sum(a.value) val                  
>    FROM TABLE1 a
>    JOIN TABLE3 c ON (a.d_no=c.d_no AND a.s_code=c.s_code)
>    JOIN TABLE2 b ON (c.segment_id=b.cat AND c.b_id=b.sub_cat)
>    WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL 
>    GROUP BY 2,1,3   
>   UNION ALL
>    SELECT a.d_no no,a.s_code code, b.type type, sum(a.value) val                  
>    FROM TABLE4 a 
>    JOIN TABLE3 c ON (a.d_no=c.d_no AND a.s_code=c.s_code)
>    JOIN TABLE2 b ON (c.segment_id=b.cat AND c.b_id=b.sub_cat)
>    WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL 
>    GROUP BY 2,1,3) x
> GROUP BY 2,1,3  --same thing as using column names btw
> ```

2. Run this statement before running the query [1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1152.htm):

> SET EXPLAIN ON;

You'll will be able to see the "query plan". It explains how indexes are used and what kind of join are in work, etc.
It is very usefull to see if Informix can fetch the records in a table by using one of the indexes of that table or if, unfortunatly, Informix has to read the table sequentially to fetch them.

Answer (score 1):

#### Asking SQL Performance Questions

When you ask a question in SQL, it is helpful to give at least an outline schema of the tables, showing the relevant columns and defining primary key and relevant foreign key constraints.  It is usually helpful to give some sample data — though for a question about returning 9 million rows, you won't give anything like a full set of data.  But some sample data is a help as long as it illustrates any data oddities.

Also, for performance problems, some of the key questions are:

- How big are the tables?
- How many rows (`systables.nrows`)?
- How many columns (`systables.ncols`)?
- What is the size of each row in bytes (`systables.rowsize`)?
- What indexes exist on each table on the columns referenced in the query?

This is crucial information for evaluating performance concerns.

#### Analyzing Your Query

As already noted by others in comments and answers, you should aim to use the modern (meaning SQL-92 or later) explicit JOIN notation in the query.

You show the query as:

```
select x.no ,x.code ,x.type ,sum(x.val) as val from 
(SELECT a.d_no as no,a.s_code as code, b.type as type, sum(a.value) as val                  
FROM TABLE1 a, TABLE2 b,TABLE3 c
WHERE c.segment_id=b.cat AND c.b_id=b.sub_cat
AND a.terminated_date is null AND a.d_no=c.d_no AND a.s_code=c.s_code
GROUP BY b.type ,b.cat,b.sub_cat, no, code 
union all
SELECT a.d_no as no,a.s_code as code,     
b.type as type,sum(a.value) as val                  
FROM TABLE4 a, TABLE2 b, TABLE3 c
WHERE c.segment_id=b.cat AND c.b_id=b.sub_cat
AND a.terminated_date is null AND a.d_no=c.d_no AND a.s_code=c.s_code
GROUP BY b.type ,b.cat,b.sub_cat, no, code) x
group by x.code ,x.no ,x.type
```

From this, we can deduce that there are 4 tables, with columns:

- TABLE1 — `d_no`, `s_code`, `value`, `terminated_date`, …
- TABLE2 — `cat`, `sub_cat`, `type`, …
- TABLE3 — `d_no`, `s_code`, `segment_id`, `b_id`, …
- TABLE4 — `d_no`, `s_code`, `value`, `terminated_date`, …

As far as the query is concerned, `TABLE1` and `TABLE4` have the same schema.

#### Rewriting with JOIN notation

The first stage is to rewrite and reformat the query so that the structure is more easily understandable.  It is simple to transform your query into:

```
SELECT x.no, x.code, x.type, SUM(x.val) AS val
  FROM (SELECT a.d_no AS no, a.s_code AS code, b.type AS type, SUM(a.value) AS val
          FROM TABLE1 a
          JOIN TABLE3 c ON a.d_no = c.d_no AND a.s_code = c.s_code
          JOIN TABLE2 b ON c.segment_id = b.cat AND c.b_id = b.sub_cat
         WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL
         GROUP BY b.type, b.cat, b.sub_cat, no, code
        UNION ALL
        SELECT a.d_no AS no, a.s_code AS code, b.type AS type, SUM(a.value) AS val
          FROM TABLE4 a
          JOIN TABLE3 c ON a.d_no = c.d_no AND a.s_code = c.s_code
          JOIN TABLE2 b ON c.segment_id = b.cat AND c.b_id = b.sub_cat
         WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL
         GROUP BY b.type, b.cat, b.sub_cat, no, code
       ) AS x
 GROUP BY x.code, x.no, x.type
```

#### Simplifying the inner GROUP BY lists

The two halves of the inner (UNION ALL) query both have the GROUP BY clause:

```
GROUP BY b.type, b.cat, b.sub_cat, no, code
```

However, including the `b.cat` and `b.sub_cat` columns in the groups simply gives more different values to be combined in the UNION ALL query.  As you simply group these combined results over just `no`, `code`, and `b.type` in the outer query, there is no benefit to mentioning `b.cat` or `b.sub_cat`.  That simplifies and revises the query to:

```
SELECT x.d_no AS no, x.s_code AS code, x.type, SUM(x.val) AS val
  FROM (SELECT a.d_no AS d_no, a.s_code AS s_code, b.type AS type, SUM(a.value) AS val
          FROM TABLE1 a
          JOIN TABLE3 c ON a.d_no = c.d_no AND a.s_code = c.s_code
          JOIN TABLE2 b ON c.segment_id = b.cat AND c.b_id = b.sub_cat
         WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL
         GROUP BY b.type, a.d_no, a.s_code
        UNION ALL
        SELECT a.d_no AS d_no, a.s_code AS s_code, b.type AS type, SUM(a.value) AS val
          FROM TABLE4 a
          JOIN TABLE3 c ON a.d_no = c.d_no AND a.s_code = c.s_code
          JOIN TABLE2 b ON c.segment_id = b.cat AND c.b_id = b.sub_cat
         WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL
         GROUP BY b.type, a.d_no, a.s_code
       ) AS x
 GROUP BY x.code, x.no, x.type
```

#### Move joins out of UNION ALL query

In fact, it is probably beneficial to move the joins out of the UNION ALL query, since the joins are to the same tables.

```
SELECT x.d_no AS no, x.s_code AS code, b.type, SUM(x.val) AS val
  FROM (SELECT a.d_no AS d_no, a.s_code AS s_code, SUM(a.value) AS val
          FROM TABLE1 a
         WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL
         GROUP BY a.d_no, a.s_code
        UNION ALL
        SELECT a.d_no AS d_no, a.s_code AS s_code, SUM(a.value) AS val
          FROM TABLE4 a
         WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL
         GROUP BY a.d_no, a.s_code
       ) AS x
  JOIN TABLE3 c ON x.d_no = c.d_no AND x.s_code = c.s_code
  JOIN TABLE2 b ON c.segment_id = b.cat AND c.b_id = b.sub_cat
 GROUP BY x.code, x.no, b.type
```

#### Move SUM out of UNION ALL query

This is the first step where I'm not reasonably certain that there is a performance benefit to the change.

```
SELECT x.d_no AS no, x.s_code AS code, b.type, SUM(x.val) AS val
  FROM (SELECT a.d_no AS d_no, a.s_code AS s_code, a.value AS val
          FROM TABLE1 a
         WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT a.d_no AS d_no, a.s_code AS s_code, a.value AS val
          FROM TABLE4 a
         WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL
       ) AS x
  JOIN TABLE3 c ON x.d_no = c.d_no AND x.s_code = c.s_code
  JOIN TABLE2 b ON c.segment_id = b.cat AND c.b_id = b.sub_cat
 GROUP BY x.code, x.no, b.type
```

This defers the grouping and aggregation until after the result of UNION ALL is produced, but avoids calculating sums of sums.  Whether that is beneficial is best determined by looking at query plans and measurement on the systems.

#### Do summations before joining

It may be better to do the joins after you've done the summations.  That would be done like this, assuming that moving the summations out of the UNION ALL query gives a performance benefit:

```
SELECT y.no, y.code, b.type, y.val
  FROM (SELECT x.d_no AS no, x.s_code AS code, SUM(x.val) AS val
          FROM (SELECT a.d_no AS d_no, a.s_code AS s_code, a.value AS val
                  FROM TABLE1 a
                 WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT a.d_no AS d_no, a.s_code AS s_code, a.value AS val
                  FROM TABLE4 a
                 WHERE a.terminated_date IS NULL
               ) AS x
         GROUP BY x.d_no, x.s_code
       ) AS y
  JOIN TABLE3 c ON y.no = c.d_no AND y.code = c.s_code
  JOIN TABLE2 b ON c.segment_id = b.cat AND c.b_id = b.sub_cat
```

You can make a similar change even if the 'move summations out of UNION ALL query' optimization is actually a pessimization.

#### Warnings

None of the revised SQL has been tested — the question does not provide the schema or any sample data to make testing easy.  I've made some assumptions about the joining chain from TABLE1/TABLE4 to TABLE3 and then TABLE2 that are plausible, but not guaranteed.  I'm assuming that a single row from TABLE1 is only associated with a single row in TABLE3 and hence to a single row in TABLE2.  If that isn't justified, the analysis needs to be reviewed, starting at the 'move joins out of the UNION ALL query' step.

#### Summary

The changes shown should speed up the query, pretty much regardless of the table sizes and the indexes that exist.  You should also study which indexes exist and which extra ones might be beneficial, which requires knowledge of the primary key and foreign key constraints on the tables, and also the table sizes.  Indexes slow update operations but can often speed up query operations.  You should not over-index your tables, but ensuring that the correct indexes are present can make a dramatic difference to query performance.  You should also ensure that the table statistics are up to date.  This is much less of an issue since the 'auto update statistics' feature was added to Informix, but you should ensure that it works correctly.